# How can I generate gpg keys in scripts without leaving gpg-agent running?

Tags: linux, gpg, gpg-agent

Recent versions of `gpg` launch a persistent user process (`gpg-agent`) when generating keys. This process remains running even after the command terminates. I want to change this behavior.

Currently, I'm using `unshare` and PID namespaces to isolate and kill off anything that `gpg` leaves running. Unfortunately, this approach requires elevated privileges that may not always be available (root and access to pid/mount namespace).

Is there a way for a script to "cleanly" generate gpg keys using `gpg` without

1. leaving processes running, or
2. requiring elevated privileges?

For the sake of completion, the following roughly illustrates my current setup:

```
sudo unshare -fp --mount-proc sh -c 'gpg --homedir /tmp/TEMP_DIR --generate-key --batch; kill -9 -1' <<EOF
Key-Type: DSA
Key-Length: 768
Name-Real: TEMPKEY
Name-Comment: TEMPKEY
Name-Email: noreply@localhost
Expire-Date: 0
%no-protection
EOF
```

Comment: `gpg2` has a new option `--no-autostart` to not start an agent.

Comment: `gpg` (GnuPG 2.2.4) refuses to start for me when `--no-autostart` is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to stop the agent once you no longer need it:

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

Since you’re using a custom home directory, you need to set `GNUPGHOME` or specify `--homedir`:

```
GNUPGHOME=/tmp/TEMP_DIR gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

If you want to stop all GnuPG-related processes, specify `all` instead of `gpg-agent`.

Comment: For cases like mine that involve a custom home directory, you need to also set the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable. Also, for my purpose, specifying `all` instead of `gpg-agent` appears to be more appropriate:  `GNUPGHOME=/tmp/TEMP_DIR gpgconf --kill all`

Comment: Thanks, I’ve added all that to the answer.